# How to print the name of the symbols of ELF files like the nm?

Tags: c, casting, elf, nm

I know the name of the symbols are in the shstrtab. 
But I don't get how to catch them. 
Should I cast my shstrab into a Elf64_Sym so that I can use the st_name?

```
Elf64_Shdr      *shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *) (data + elf->e_shoff);
Elf64_Shdr      *symtab;
Elf64_Shdr      *shstrtab;
Elf64_Shdr      *strtab;
char            *str = (char *) (data + shdr[elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset);

for (int i = 0; i < elf->e_shnum; i++) {
  if (shdr[i].sh_size) {
    printf("%s\n", &str[shdr[i].sh_name]);
    if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".symtab") == 0)
      symtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
    if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".shstrtab") == 0)
      shstrtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
    if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".strtab") == 0)
      strtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
  }
}

str = (char *) shstrtab;
for (size_t i = 0; i < (symtab->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym *)); i ++) {
  printf("%s\n", &str[shstrtab[i].sh_name]);
}
```

Comment: I only understood it's about some cats...

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about some data type.  You should post a code snippet that shows where you are stuck so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Elf64_Shdr      *shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *) (data + elf->e_shoff);
Elf64_Shdr      *symtab;
Elf64_Shdr      *shstrtab;
Elf64_Shdr      *strtab;
char            *str = (char *) (data + shdr[elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset);
 for (int i = 0; i < elf->e_shnum; i++) {
  if (shdr[i].sh_size) {
   if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".symtab") == 0)
    symtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
   if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".shstrtab") == 0)
    shstrtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
   if (strcmp(&str[shdr[i].sh_name], ".strtab") == 0)
    strtab = (Elf64_Shdr *) &shdr[i];
  }
        }

Comment: You should be using the ELF library (`libelf.so` or thereabouts) to read and analyze the data.  I've no idea what you think 'cats' are doing — did one tread on your keyboard as you were typing that?

Comment: Put the code into the question where you can format it, not in a comment where you can't.

Comment: I'm trying to recode nm without the flas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I cast my shstrab into a Elf64_Sym so that I can use the st_name?

No.

Here is the loop you want:

```
Elf64_Sym *sym = (Elf64_Sym*) (data + symtab->sh_offset);
str = (char*) (data + strtab->sh_offset);

for (size_t i = 0; i < symtab->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym); i++) {
  printf("%s\n", str + sym[i].st_name);
}
```

Comment: but there is some extra symbols and the program crash

Comment: @EmployedRussian what's **data** supposed to be? Can I just use `str = (char*) strtab->sh_offset?`

Comment: @Trey `data` is supposed to point to file *contents* loaded into memory usually by either `mmap` or by `read`ing it into a buffer. No, `strtab->sh_offset` will *not* work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `symtab->sh_size / symtab->sh_entsize` not like `symtab->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym *)` as the post above says