# Static ELF alternative to dlsym

Tags: elf, dlsym

Is it possible to lookup the location of a function using ELF? Similar to what

```
void *f = dlopen(NULL,..);
void *func = dlsym(f, "myfunc");
```

does, but without requiring `-rdynamic` during compilation?

I can see using `nm` that the naming of the items is still present in a compiled binary?:

```
0000000000400716 T lookup
0000000000400759 T main
```

Can I use this information to locate the items once the program is loaded into memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use this information to locate the items once the program is loaded into memory?

You sure can: iterate over all symbols in the `a.out` until you find the matching one. Example code to iterate over symbols is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843218/50617). Or use [libelf](http://em386.blogspot.com/2007/03/quick-libelf-guide.html).

If you need to perform multiple symbol lookups, iterate once (slow) over all symbols, build a map from symbol name to its address, and perform lookups using that map.

**Update:**

> The example you point to seems incomplete? It uses data and elf, where are they coming from?

Yes, you need to apply a little bit of elbow grease to that example.

The `data` is location in memory where the `a.out` is `read` into, or (better) `mmap`ed.

You can either `mmap` the `a.out` yourself, or find the existing mapping via e.g. `getauxval(AT_PHDR)` rounded down to page size.

The `ehdr` is `(ElfW(Ehdr) *)data` (that is, `data` cast to `Elf32_Ehdr` or `Elf64_Ehdr` as appropriate.

If this is not clear, then you probably should just use `libelf`, which takes care of the details for you.

> Also, does ELF only allow me to find the name of the symbol, or can it actually give me the pointer to the in memory location of the symbol?

It can give you both: `str + sym[i].st_name` is the name, `sym[i].st_value` is the pointer (the value displayed by `nm`).

> (presumably the e.g. 0000000000400716 is some relative base address, not the actual in memory location, right?)

No, actually (for this binary) it's the absolute address.

Position-independent binaries do use relative addresses (so you'll need something like `getauxval` mentioned above to find the base location of such executable), but this particular binary looks like `ET_EXEC` (use `readelf -h a.out` to verify this). The address `0x400000` is *typical* address for loading of non-PIE executables on Linux x86_64 (which is probably what your system is).

Comment: Two questions: The example you point to seems incomplete? It uses `data` and `elf`, where are they coming from?

Also, does ELF only allow me to find the name of the symbol, or can it actually give me the pointer to the _in memory_ location of the symbol ? (presumably the e.g. 0000000000400716 is some relative base address, not the actual in memory location, right?)