# How to extract symbols and see their offset in the file

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, symbols, elf, nm

I can extract symbols using the "nm -a -D" command.
But is there a way to extract the symbol names with an offset from the start of the file?

For example,

```
nm -D ./libc.so
```

Shows me this -

```
...
00000000000f8c60 T xdr_wrapstring
00000000000f7cc0 T xencrypt
00000000000bd230 T __xmknod
00000000000bd2a0 T __xmknodat
000000000003ec70 T __xpg_basename
00000000000314b0 W __xpg_sigpause
0000000000080db0 T __xpg_strerror_r
00000000000f6090 T xprt_register
00000000000f61f0 T xprt_unregister
00000000000bd110 T __xstat
00000000000bd110 T __xstat64
```

Now, I want to get the offset of the symbol names from the start of the file in the same way that the "strings -t x" command shows the offset of the strings -

```
strings -t x ./libc.so | grep __xstat
  13af9 __xstat
  13fac __xstat64
```

How can I do this?

(I can't use the "strings" command on the output of the "nm" command because there could be multiple instances of the same symbol string in the file and I want to get the exact offset of the symbol (not just some string that is the same as the symbol))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a way to extract the symbol names with an offset from the start of the file?

There sure is: `nm` is doing it (in order to print the names).

You should be aware that there could be *two* symbol tables: a regular one and a dynamic one (`nm -D` displays the latter).

The symbols themselves are stored in `.dynsym` section (or `.symtab` section for the regular symbol table), and they contain the offset into `.dynstr` section (which actually contains the names).

So adding `".dynstr".sh_offset` + `"symbol".st_name` will give you offset of the symbol name in the file.

Sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843218/50617). (The code uses `.symtab` and `.strtab`; you'll need to adjust it to use `.dynsym` and `.dynstr` to print the dynamic symbol table.)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the offset by yourself, or obtain it via -F/--file-offsets option of objdump.

```
   -F
   --file-offsets
       When disassembling sections, whenever a symbol is displayed,
       also display the file offset of the region of data that is
       about to be dumped.  If zeroes are being skipped, then when
       disassembly resumes, tell the user how many zeroes were
       skipped and the file offset of the location from where the
       disassembly resumes.  When dumping sections, display the file
       offset of the location from where the dump starts.
```

For example, to get the file offset of strlen symbol in libc:

```
$ objdump --file-offsets -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep strlen
000000000009f630 <strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5> (File Offset: 0x9f630):
```