# Is it possible to call invisible functions of an so

Tags: shared-libraries, elf, linux

I'm using an so which can not be rebuilt. But the advanced APIs of the so are not exported(I found the hidden function symbols with objdump). So is it possible to look up the function address by decoding the elf loaded into memory?

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59637959/50617) question.

> is it possible to look up the function address by decoding the elf loaded into memory?

If the symbol is visible to `objdump`, then it is present in the symbol table of the DSO, and yes, its address can be programmatically extracted.

This isn't very hard. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48833887/50617).