# How to get main function address from dynamically added library .so?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, code-injection

I had dynamically load a shared library for target process. Target process has a function
`void printNum()`. Is it possible to get it address in shred library?
actually i need start address of .text segment + function offset, but in target process i can get it with `&printNum`, is it posiible to do the same but in shared librarry?

Comment: Yes, the shared library can access external symbols.

Comment: POSIX provides [`dlopen`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) and [`dlsym`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlsym.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get it address in shred library?

Maybe.

It's easy if the main executable *exports* the symbol in its dynamic symbol table. If so, you can access its address using the same `&printNum` syntax.

To see whether the main executable exports the symbol, use `nm -D a.out | grep ' printNum'`.

If the main executable doesn't export the symbol, and you try to access it from the `foo.so` with `&printNum`, your `dlopen("foo.so", ...)` will fail with `"printNum: unresolved symbol"` or a similar error.

If you can't rebuild the main executable with e.g. `-rdynamic` flag, things get trickier.

If the main executable has symbol table (i.e. it is no stripped), the function will be visible in the output from `nm a.out`. You can read the symbol table using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843218/50617), and obtain the address of `printNum` from it. If `a.out` is position-independent, you will also need to find the address where it is loaded, using e.g. `dl_iterate_phdr()`.

If the main executable doesn't have symbol table (i.e. it is stripped), then there is no way to find where `printNum` actually is, and the answer in that case is "no".